# Apache alias for all URLs except index.php

Tags: php, apache2, alias

I have two folders on the server.

```
/var/www/core
/var/www/instances/first
```

An entry point for each instance is located under the path `/var/www/instances/first`. There are

- `index.php` file
- `config.php` file
- `uploads/` folder

So at first server has to open `index.php` file and then forward all requests to another folder `/var/www/core`.
`index.php` content

```
// ... some code ... 
require '../../core/index.php';
```

As I understand I have to use Alias for reaching the goal. I have the following virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName first.com
ServerAlias www.first.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/instances/first/

Alias /uploads /var/www/instances/first/uploads/

<Directory /var/www/instances/first/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias / /var/www/core/

<Directory /var/www/core/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Redirect from www to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But with this config all my URLs (including first `index.php`) is forwarded to **core** folder. 
Maybe someone know how to change the config to prevent "aliasing" main `index.php` file.

P.s.: another alias for `uploads/` folder is needed and it is working well.

Comment: The alias for / means "everything". You need to alias with a name if you don't want to alias everything, just like the /uploads alias.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I need an alias for all except main `index.php` file. The flow is: load `index.php` from the instances folder, load valid config and then require `index.php` from another folder and handle the request. And the same procedure for any requests except requests to `uploads` folder (there is a valid alias for these purposes already)

Comment: What you are asking makes sense. My comment is that the Alias command with / is for everything. No exception. There is no syntax like "Alias / (except index) /somewhere/else". You need to change your overall design.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I understand that well. That's why I've decided to ask community))